# Place image on top of all "layers" on iOS screen

Tags: ios

What are the constraints/alternatives to place an image that stays on top of all iOS "layers" and windows. Think of it as a lock screen but that still allows you to interact with you phone, meaning browse, answer calls, etc. The image will be displayed in a transparent way (say 40%) and will be launched by an application.

Comment: inside your app a modal view in your key window's root view controller could do the job, maybe; but you have not specified whether your are looking for sandboxed solution or something which you can put top on every screen, every time during using the phone.

Comment: Do you mean a view on top of all applications?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are asking for but if you are looking for a way to add some code once and it shows everywhere on each of your ViewController then there really is no way to do that.

What you can do is

- Use UIToolBar
- add buttons to that tool bar
- Add that tool bar to each ViewController in storyboard (where you need them)
- Create a global function / method that you can call in from any ViewController that has the button actions in it. That way you edit the code once in one place and use it every where.

If you don't like UIToolBar then

- you can add your own UIImageView and add a transparent background to it
- Add your buttons on the UIImageView. (You will have to add constraints)
- then show that on every ViewController

If all this seems to much work then you can use existing controls [HERE](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=menu) and see which one fits your needs.

This maybe a good one - [FCVerticalMenu](https://github.com/filippocamillo/FCVerticalMenu)